# Unable to initialize any output collector in CDH5.3

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

```
15/05/24 06:11:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1432456238397_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Unable to initialize any output collector
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
```

I am using CDH 5.3 cloudera quickstart, I wrote MapReduce Program. When i run that on shell i getting above exception.

Can any one please help me on this, how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

The error **"Unable to initialize any output collector"** indicates that the job failed to start the container's, there can be multiple reasons for the same. However, one must review the container logs at hdfs to identify the cause the error.

In this specific instance, the value of `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb` value was entered greater than `2047 MB`, however the maximum value which it allows is `2047 MB`, thus anything above its causes the jobs to fail marking the value provided as Invalid.

**Solution:**

Set the value of `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb < 2048MB`

**Reference:**

https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/205649987-Map-Reduce-job-failed-with-Unable-to-initialize-any-output-collector-

[CDH5.2: MR, Unable to initialize any output collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926571/cdh5-2-mr-unable-to-initialize-any-output-collector)

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/HBase-MapReduce-Job-Error-java-io-IOException-Unable-to/td-p/23786